# Unzipping files using JSZIP and useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, asynchronous, blob

Why is my State not updating correctly?

My goal was to load files from zip file stored in db to my "Dropbox" clone. Unfortunately I got only last file of zip to load:

```
 zipContent.forEach((relativePath, zipEntry) => {
      zipEntry.async("blob").then((blob) => {
        const n = new File([blob], relativePath, { type: blob.type });
        updateFileList([...fileList, { id: nanoid(), file: n }]);
      });
    });
```

For some unknown to me reason I am only getting the last zip file to load properly :(

Comment: Try using the function version of updateFileList, ie `updateFileList(currentList => [...currentList, {id: nanoid(), file: n}])`

Comment: @James Thanks a lot. I totally forgot about this thing. It works perfectly!